# With tasks, continueWith and WhenAll(), when continue, when finish task or when finish ConitueWith?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have few tasks that each one has a `ContinueWith` that use the result of the task. Something like that:

```
Task myTask01 = myMethod01Async().ContinueWith((a) => //do somenthing with 
a.result);

Task myTask02 = myMethod02Async().ContinueWith((a) => //do somenthing with a.result);

Task.WhenAll(myTask01, myTask02);
```

I know that WhenAll waits until all tasks in the paramaters are done. But in this case that I have a `ContinueWith`, I don't know if whenAll waits untill all `ContinueWith` are finished or continue when `Task01` and `Task02` finish, so the code continue although the `ContinueWith` code is still running.

Comment: _"I don't know if whenAll waits untill all ContinueWith are finished or continue when Task01 and Task02 finish"_ -- the tasks `Task01` and `Task02` _are_ exactly the representation of when the `ContinueWith()` finishes. Your question doesn't make much sense,  because you're implying they are different, when in fact they are the same. Of course, if you'd just read the documentation, or even _tried_ an example, you'd have been able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new task, so by using Task. WhenAll, you are in fact waiting for the tasks that are returned from `ContinueWith` and not from `myMethod01Async` and `myMethod02Async`.

So yes, Task. WhenAll will wait for the code inside `ContinueWith` to finish.

Comment: then I don't understand why it does not work like that in my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062234/how-to-implement-and-run-the-collection-of-tasks-sequentially-in-parallel