# How to implement and run the collection of tasks sequentially + in parallel?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a list of `Tasks`, where each element represents `async Task` method call. When I construct this list - I make decision on whether this `Task` needs to be run after the previous one has completed or in parallel with it (based on configuration settings). However, this does not work as expected - the part from `ContinueWith` lives its own life, no matter what options I use for it (please see piece of source code below).

Log - now I have setting saying the tasks need to be run sequentially (`IsSynchronousStart == true`):

> 2021-02-05 13:20:53.616 +02:00 [INF] BatchMasterModule, InitAsync started

> 2021-02-05 13:20:55.258 +02:00 [INF] SqlBatchJobModule, RunAsync started

> 2021-02-05 13:22:11.711 +02:00 [INF] SqlBatchJobModule, RunAsync ended

> 2021-02-05 13:22:11.713 +02:00 [INF] FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync started

> 2021-02-05 13:22:11.713 +02:00 [INF] Batch tasks status is RanToCompletion

> 2021-02-05 13:22:14.644 +02:00 [INF] BatchMasterModule, InitAsync started

> 2021-02-05 13:22:16.224 +02:00 [INF] SqlBatchJobModule, RunAsync started

> 2021-02-05 13:22:20.638 +02:00 [INF] FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync ended (!!!)

There are two tasks here:
`batchJobTasks[0]` matches `SqlBatchJobModule`, `batchJobTasks[1]` matches `FileBatchJobModule`.

"FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync started" - this had to be called after "SqlBatchJobModule, RunAsync ended" (this is SOMETIMES run as expected, sometimes - after "Batch tasks status is RanToCompletion")

"FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync ended" - this had to be called before "Batch tasks status is RanToCompletion" (is NEVER OK now)

"BatchMasterModule, InitAsync started" - this represents a scheduled invocation of the same method in time

UPDATE

1. the source code of `InitAsync` (reduced - the part related to `Task` list creation retained):

   ```
    public class BatchMasterModule : IBatchMasterModule
    {
        public async Task InitAsync([DisableConcurrentExecutionKeyAttribute] FullBatchKeyDto batchKey)
        {
            ...

            var batchJobs = await _batchJobAppService.GetListForServerAsync(batchKey);

            ...

            var batchJobTasks = new List<Task>();

            BatchJobDto prevJob = null;

            foreach (var batchJob in batchJobs)
            {
                if (_batchJobModuleFactory.TryGet(batchJob.Module?.Runtime, out IBatchJobModule module))
                {
                    ...
                    var context = new BatchJobContext
                    (
                        _serviceProvider,
                        batchKey.TenantId,
                        batchJob
                    );

                    ...

                    if (prevJob == null || prevJob.IsSynchronousStart.Value == false)
                    {
                        batchJobTasks.Add(module.RunAsync(context));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var previousTask = batchJobTasks.Last();
                        previousTask = previousTask.ContinueWith(result => module.RunAsync(context));
                    }

                    prevJob = batchJob;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(batchJob.Module.Runtime));
                }
            }

            await Task
                .WhenAll(batchJobTasks)
                .ContinueWith(result =>
                {
                    if (batch.PrintReport.HasValue && batch.PrintReport.Value == true)
                    {
                        //TODO: perform reporting only if successful job execution?
                        Log.Information($"Batch tasks status is {result.Status}. OK, will print report at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                });
          }
     }
   ```
2. `FileBatchJobModule` - which is not called as expected - instead of being called when the previous module - `SqlBatchModule` - is completed it is called in some random moments and completed after `WhenAll` completes, not before (as I would expect too):

   ```
    public class FileBatchJobModule : IBatchJobModule
    {
        public Func<IBatchJobContext, Task> OnCompletedAsync { get; set; }

        public async Task RunAsync(IBatchJobContext context)
        {
            //TODO
            Log.Information($"FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync started at {DateTime.Now}");
            const int defaultDelay = 15000;
            await Task.Delay(
                context.Parameters.TryGetValue("delay", out string delayString)
                ? (int.TryParse(delayString, out int delay) ? delay : defaultDelay)
                : defaultDelay);
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"Updating text from async call at {DateTime.Now}{Environment.NewLine}");
            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(
                @"C:\CentralTools\Files\filebatchjobmodule.txt",
                FileMode.Append,
                FileAccess.Write,
                FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096,
                useAsync: true))
            {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
            };
            if (OnCompletedAsync != null)
            {
                await OnCompletedAsync.Invoke(context);
            }
            Log.Information($"FileBatchJobModule, RunAsync ended at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Could you add sample code that shows how the tasks are created?

Comment: @Slugart well... tried to do my best. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by switching from List to List<Func>. I felt it could be the case...

```
                if (prevJob == null || prevJob.IsSynchronousStart.Value == false)
                {
                    batchJobTasks.Add(async () => await module.RunAsync(context));
                }
                else
                {
                    var previousTask = batchJobTasks.Last();
                    batchJobTasks.RemoveAt(batchJobTasks.Count - 1);
                    batchJobTasks.Add(async () => { await previousTask(); await module.RunAsync(context); });
                }
```